# How do I .bind Enterkey <Return> to a button only if inside textbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I have A Note Taking Program and currently I can type in a Keyword in TextBox-1 and hit Enter to get my notes displayed in a TextBox-2.

The only way I can find how to bind Enter  to a button is for it to always be bound to that button. Or I can bind Enter to a function. I would rather have it bound to the button/function only if I am currently inside textBox-1.

I don't even know if it is possible because I can not find any references to something similar to my needs.

Currently I have my Enter key bound like this:

```
root.bind('<Return>', kw_entry)
```

This calls the function kw_entry when I hit Enter.

```
def kw_entry(event=None):
    e1Current = keywordEntry.get().lower()
    if e1Current in notes:  # e1Corrent is just the current text in TextBox-1
        root.text.delete(1.0, END)
        root.text.insert(tkinter.END, notes[e1Current])
        root.text.see(tkinter.END)
    else:
        root.text.delete(1.0, END)
        root.text.insert(tkinter.END, "Not a Keyword")
        root.text.see(tkinter.END)
```

For the most part this works fine however I also want to edit the notes being displayed and the problem is I can not hit Enter while in TextBox-2 because Enter is bound to call the function kw_entry. This is a problem because it resets everything in TextBox-2.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Bind the textbox widget to <Return> rather than `root`.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the binding to apply when focus is on a specific widget, put the binding on that widget.

In the following example, if you press return while in the text widget then a message will be printed on the console. If you are in the entry widget, that won't happen.

```
import tkinter as tk

def foo(event):
    print("you pressed return")
    # the following prevents the enter key from inserting
    # a newline. If you remove the line, the newline will
    # be entered after this function runs
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
text = tk.Text(root)

entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
text.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

text.bind("<Return>", foo)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @scotty3785 & Bryan Oakley: That did exactly what I needed it to do :). I assume that binding <Return> to the widget only maters while in the widget and that leaves me open to bind <Return> to other widgets, correct?